# Is it possible to access sales data from inside an app?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, google-play, app-store

Im considering trying out a new monetisation strategy for a freemium iOS & Android app.

The basic idea is the user pays to remove ads in the app but I display the total number of sales the IAP has made (from all players worldwide). I then set sales milestones where I promise to add new levels once the milestone is broken.

I was wondering if anyone knows whether its possible to pull sales data directly from the store from within the app on iOS or Google Play?

So I can display something like "New levels will be added at 1000 sales. Current sales: 780"

I can do this if host a file on a server somewhere and update it manually with new sales figure daily but it'd be better if I could automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.firebase.com/ there are some things you can do to alter the behavior of the app even after its installed. It might be possible without setting up a full blown API but we need more details to know for sure.